# Show the First 10 Row in Group By Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

```
select COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, count(COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME) as Number_Of_Schools
from CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS group by COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME order by 2 desc
```

I wrote the above sql query to get the result set which explain the community area name which has most number of schools, The results is like that 
But how can show only the first 10 colums?? I use 'Limit 10'. But it is showing some errors.

[image]

```
select Top 10 COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, count(COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME) as Number_Of_Schools
from CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS group by COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME order by 2 desc 
Limit 10;
```

Error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'Limit'.
```

Comment: Could you please post the error as well and one more thing if you are using SQL then it supports **top** not **limit**

Comment: Do you really mean top 10 COLUMNS or you mean top 10 ROWS instead?

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your case, simply putting `TOP 10` should work.

```
select TOP 10 COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME, count(COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME) as Number_Of_Schools
from CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS 
group by COMMUNITY_AREA_NAME 
order by 2 desc
```

`LIMIT` is not supported directly by SQL Server, if you are using `SQLServer 2012+` you can use `OFFSET` and `FETCH` which works similar like `LIMIT`. You can read more about this here [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

For the older version of SQL Server, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to achieve the same.

Comment: Can you tell me why i can't use Limit here??